# Georgia Font size is different in Chrome vs Firefox / IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, fonts

[image: Georgia font used in Chrome]

*^Chrome*

[image: Georgia font used in firefox / ie]

*^Firefox/IE*

I'm trying to let the georgia font looks the same in Chrome vs IE / Firefox. In Firefox and IE everything seems to be normal. In Chrome it looks like the font size is a bit bigger.

The CSS code I use:

```
section#sect-brochure article#brochure-left {  float:left;  font-family:Georgia, Times new roman;  font-size:12px;}
```

"font-stretch" doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, don't rely on font sizes. Make your css adopt to the size of the text blocks. Browsers will treat it differently depending on the operating system, user settings and device used. Not everybody will even be able to use the font of your choice.

Comment: How do I fix that? The 'textballoon' is not resizable, so the font has to be resized to get into the balloon

Comment: That's the general error. The balloon should be designed to resize.